# jQuery blur keeps firing when two inputs are involved

Tags: jquery

I've dug around for a while on Google and here on stack Overflow and can't find anything related to this.

I've got multiple input textfields that when blurred calls a jQuery AJAX function to the server.  It works beautifully, almost.

The problem is if I have focus on one text input and then click on another one (making it in focus).  The blur event keeps getting fired with AJAX calls to the server and alerts.

Any ideas how to calm blur down so it isn't constantly firing?  There is probably something very simple that I'm not doing that might fix this.

Here's the code (ignore the {{}} and {%%} tags, this is a django template).

The inputs:

```
    <td class="tracking-text">CK Req:</td><td class="tracking-td"><input class="tracking-input" type="text" value="{{pr.checkreq|default_if_none:"&nbsp"}}" size="10"></td>
    <td class="tracking-text">LPD:</td><td class="tracking-td"><input class="tracking-input" type="text" value="{{pr.lpd|default_if_none:""}}" size="10"></td>
    <td class="tracking-text">PR#</td><td class="tracking-td"><input class="tracking-input" type="text" value="{{pr.prnumber|default_if_none:""}}" size="10"></td>
    <td class="tracking-text">DATE:</td><td class="tracking-td"><input class="tracking-input" type="text" value="{{pr.prdate|default_if_none:""}}" size="10"></td>
```

The jQuery:

```
        $('.tracking-input').blur(function(){

            $.post( "{% url buy.views.update_purchase_ajax %}",
                {pr_pk: $('span#pr_pk').html()},
                function(data){
                    alert(data.message);
                }, 'json');


        });
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alert` is causing you to again lose focus, firing off another AJAX request.

Maybe fix it by only sending the AJAX request if the input is not empty?

Is this `alert` really needed or is it just for debugging?  This is a prime example why you shouldn't use `alert` for debugging.  Use `console.log`.

Comment: The alert is just for debugging.  Wouldn't the problem have arisen then when clicking off of a single input to the rest of the page?

Comment: Okay, then if you just remove it it should stop going nuts.  Maybe try `console.log` so it doesn't affect the functionality.

Comment: it does seem to stop it if I remove it.  So it solves my problem (thank you!).  I'm still not 100% sure how the alert causes an input to think it's being blurred, then focused, then blurred..etc  But nonetheless it works, thank you again.

Comment: The `alert` takes focus when it pops up (input is blurred).  Then when you click okay on the alert focus is returned to the input.  Then the ajax from that blur returns causing this all over again and that goes on forever.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `alert()` itself.

It takes the focus away from the input when it is shown so it keeps recurring.