# jQuery on('focusout') wont trigger

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set up an auto-save when I edit input fields. I know it can be tasking for the db to do a save routine on every key up, so I figured I'll trigger it on focus out of my inputs of that specific form. However, it's not triggering anything.

My jQuery:

```
$('form#base_fields input').on('focusout', function(event) {

    alert('test');

});
```

I replaced simply my var creation and my call to my ajax save routine with an alert for test purposes, but it wont be trigger. This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" id="base_fields" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="formname" type="hidden" value="base_fields_article">
    <input name="formtable" type="hidden" value="tnt_treeview">
    <input name="nodeid" type="hidden" value="1005">
    <label for="articlenumber">article number</label>
    <div class="form-content">
        <input name="articlenumber" type="text" value="ART000001" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="articlenumber" tabindex="1">
    </div>
    <label for="articlename">article name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="articlename" type="text" value="Random article number 1" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="articlename" tabindex="2">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-globe font-size-20"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="shortdescription">Short description</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="shortdescription" type="text" value="Random article with some specifications number 1" class="form-control" placeholder="shortdescription" tabindex="3">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-globe font-size-20"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="longdescription">Long description</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="longdescription" type="text" value="Random article complete marketing text. Can go up to a lot of items" class="form-control" placeholder="longdescription" tabindex="4">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-globe font-size-20"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="EAN">EAN-13</label>
    <div class="form-content">
        <input name="EAN" type="text" min="13" max="13" class="form-control" placeholder="EAN" tabindex="5">
    </div>
</form>
```

I am not sure if focusout works this way as I think it does, can somebody nudge me in the right direction?

edit: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/09j3s28h/

Comment: This might help, though there are some jQuery plugins out there too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621214/auto-save-form-field-inputs-using-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: The alert in your codes works for me. Did you apply another plugin on your form so it regenerates the elements (like WYSIWYG editors)?

Comment: Per jQuery docs focusout means clicking away from an input, not moving the mouse away from the form. https://api.jquery.com/focusout/. Some approach this as a timed autosave, maybe you want to autosave when someone leaves the document entirely?

Comment: @NathanielFlick thats a typo, i meant on input. Hence my jquery has it's target on the input.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour no WYSIWYG editor actually even linked in my JS. I do have JStree running on the side, but i doubt that would be an issue. Its not in that form.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I set up a jsfiddle, in which it wont work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some spitting arround, i combined some awnsers to come to the following

```
$(document).on('focusout','#base_fields input',function(){

    console.log('test');

});
```

With an alert for testing purposes, it completely borked on me being stuck in an endless loop, but calling it via document.on and then using the focusout and the id of the input as a guider, it did the trick.

**Reference**:

[jQuery Focusout of input not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265571/jquery-focusout-of-input-not-working)

[jQuery blur keeps firing when two inputs are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550331/jquery-blur-keeps-firing-when-two-inputs-are-involved)